# Why sometimes i'm getting exception in Backgroundworker do work event InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the form1 constructor i'm doing:

```
buttonSnap.Enabled = false;
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then i have a button click:

```
private void buttonSnap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearGraphics = true;
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.Clear();
            this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = null;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            buttonSnap.Enabled = false;
        }
```

And in the backgroundworker do event i'm adding to a listBox items each item is a captured window:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.IsHandleCreated)
                {
                    listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.Add("Minimized Windows"); }));
                    listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray()); }));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string t = "exception " + ee.ToString();
            }
        }
```

This is a link for WindowSnap.cs class:

[WindowSnap.cs](http://pastebin.com/K5qswncs)

And this is a link for WindowSnapCollection.cs:

[WindowSnapCollection.cs](http://pastebin.com/QqfeMaax)

In the WindowSnap.cs there is the method GetallWindows:

```
public static WindowSnapCollection GetAllWindows(bool minimized, bool specialCapturring)
        {
            windowSnaps = new WindowSnapCollection();
            countMinimizedWindows = minimized;//set minimized flag capture
            useSpecialCapturing = specialCapturring;//set specialcapturing flag
            EnumWindowsCallbackHandler callback = new EnumWindowsCallbackHandler(EnumWindowsCallback);
            EnumWindows(callback, IntPtr.Zero);
            return new WindowSnapCollection(windowSnaps.ToArray(), true);
        }
```

Now the exception is throw sometimes on the DoWork event on the line:

```
listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray()); }));
```

The exception is:

Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

The full exception message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  Message=Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
       at MinimizeCapture.Form1.backgroundWorker1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in c:\Temp\Capture\Form1.cs:line 81
  InnerException:
```

Line 81 is:

```
listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.Add("Minimized Windows"); }));
```

Now i added in the backgroundworker do work event try and catch and sometimes it stop at the string t...in the catch. Then i added this:

if (this.IsHandleCreated)

So now sometimes it does the same problem but without stopping on the catch and throw the exception.
The same problem still exist sometimes it does the problem the exception describe sometimes not.

This : if (this.IsHandleCreated) didn't solve it.

Comment: If this is your complete _DowWork() method then you don't need a Bgw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking `this.InHandleCreated` which returns whether handle is created for current instance. I presume it is a Form. But, Immediately you call `listBoxSnap.Invoke` that's the problem. Handle for `listBoxSnap` might not have been created at that point. You need to use `listBoxSnap.InHandleCreated` instead.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (listBoxSnap.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.Add("Minimized Windows"); }));
            listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray()); }));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        string t = "exception " + ee.ToString();
    }
}
```

Also, If this is your real code, You don't need a `BackgroundWorker` at all. You're not making use of worker thread. All work is done by *Main thread* only.

I'll suggest you to do the following which is effectively same as your code(because your DoWork does nothing useful).

```
buttonSnap.Enabled = false;
this.listBoxSnap.Items.Add("Minimized Windows"); }));
this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
```